# Select multiple column with out code duplication while joining two table #active record # rails 2.3

Tags: select, join, activerecord, duplicates, ruby-on-rails-2

Let us consider two tables
table1 - name,id,publisher_name,exp_date
table2-book_id,price,discount,last_date

I have to retrieve the name, id,publisher_name from  table1 and price, last_date from table2

I wrote a code in active record rails 2

> Table1.find(:all,:select=>"table1.name,table1.publisher_name,table1.id,table2.last_date,table2.price",:joins=>"LEFT OUTER JOIN table1s on table1s.id= table2s.book_id")

in this code  by selecting multiple column name we need  write that table name repeatedly,

need a  simple code to avoid this problem

Answer (score 0):

if the selected columns are not present in both tables you don't need to write the tablename as a prefix. You also don't need to name the table2 in front of "book_id". You only need them if the column-names are ambigious.

```
Table1.find( :all, :select=> "name, publisher_name, id, last_date,  price", :joins => "LEFT OUTER JOIN table1s on table1s.id = book_id")
```